# How to get the package name of a non-built-in command?

Tags: linux, bash

Background Description:

I pull a docker image of fedora from hub.docker.com and run it. The image has been extremely slimmed for minimum size. The result is: the non-built-in command "find" is not available in the container!

I have tried `dnf install find` but no packages were found.

My question:

**How to get the package name of a non-built-in command?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using dnf search with the keyword and running to find it if you have a host already with the package installed run dnf provides and you should get your package name easily.

> dnf provides /usr/bin/find

findutils-4.5.11-6